# Making a copy of uploaded file in PHP

Tags: php, html, encryption, file-upload

In my form I'm letting my user to upload a file. In the form tag, I've added 'enctype="multipart/form-data"'. I'm trying to make a copy of this file and want to save it in another location. When the 'enctype' attribute is not set, it's working well but after setting 'enctype' attribute, I'm unable to copy the file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the move_uploaded_file funtion?

Comment: Hi @Am, I'm not using that function. I want to make a copy of that file. move_uploaded_file funtion does the same?

Comment: you should really use the move_uploaded_file as it does some security checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how enctype can be a problem but have you tried this:

```
$destLocation = "c:\xxx\yyy\" . $_FILES["input_name"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["input_name"]["temp_name"], $destLocation);
```

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file()` in [php file upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) just works fine with 'enctype'

Answer (score 1):

Without setting the form with enctype="mualtipart/form-data" you cannot upload a file. And you must be able to copy your file using move_uploaded_file() function.